# Numerical integration over non-uniform grid in matlab. Is there any function?

Tags: matlab, math

I've got function values in a vector `f` and also the vector containing values of the argument `x`. I need to find the define integral value of `f`. But the argument vector `x` is not uniform. Is there any function in Matlab that deals with integration over non-uniform grids?

Answer (score 6):

Taken from help :

> Z = trapz(X,Y) computes the integral of Y with respect to X using
>       the trapezoidal method.  X and Y must be vectors of the same
>       length, or X must be a column vector and Y an array whose first
>       non-singleton dimension is length(X).  trapz operates along this
>       dimension.

As you can see `x` does not have to be uniform.

For instance:

```
x = sort(rand(100,1)); %# Create random values of x in [0,1]
y = x;
trapz( x, y)
```

Returns:

```
ans =

    0.4990
```

Another example:

```
x = sort(rand(100,1)); %# Create random values of x in [0,1]
y = x.^2;
trapz( x, y)
```

returns:

```
ans =

    0.3030
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrey. I think that suits to me.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your function (and how `x` is distributed), you might get more accuracy by doing a `spline` interpolation through your data first:

```
pp  = spline(x,y);
quadgk(@(t) ppval(pp,t), [range])
```

That's the quick-n-dirty way. Ther is a faster and more direct approach, but that is fugly and much less transparent:

```
result = sum(sum(...
    bsxfun(@times, pp.coefs, 1./(4:-1:1)) .*...  % coefficients of primitive
    bsxfun(@power, diff(pp.breaks).', 4:-1:1)... % all 4 powers of shifted x-values
    ));
```

As an example why all this could be useful, I borrow the example from [here](http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=18495). The exact answer should be

```
>> pi/2/sqrt(2)*(17-40^(3/4))
ans =
     1.215778726893561e+00
```

Defining

```
>> x = [0 sort(3*rand(1,5)) 3];
>> y = (x.^3.*(3-x)).^(1/4)./(5-x);
```

we find

```
>> trapz(x,y)
ans =
    1.142392438652055e+00

>> pp  = spline(x,y);
>> tic; quadgk(@(t) ppval(pp,t), 0, 3), toc
ans =
    1.213866446458034e+00
Elapsed time is 0.017472 seconds.

>> tic; result = sum(sum(...
    bsxfun(@times, pp.coefs, 1./(4:-1:1)) .*...  % coefficients of primitive
    bsxfun(@power, diff(pp.breaks).', 4:-1:1)... % all 4 powers of shifted x-values
    )), toc
result =
    1.213866467945575e+00
Elapsed time is 0.002887 seconds.
```

So `trapz` underestimates the value by more than `0.07`. With the latter two methods, the error is an order of magnitude less. Also, the less-readable version of the `spline` approach is an order of magnitude faster.

So, armed with this knowledge: choose wisely :)

Comment: Check out Simpsons rule - that is a way to integrate the spline of the signal in one shot.

Comment: @Andrey: Hmmm...Simpson's rule is based on the *quadratic* approximation to `f(x)`, where the approximating polynomial equals `f(x)` at the end-points and midpoint...AFAIK, splines are *cubic* approximations, so how does that work?

Comment: @Andrey: Gauss-Kronrod applies nicely because it also uses a cubic approximation on each interval. I was thinking more in terms of using the info in `pp.breaks` and pp.coefs` in "some smart way" :)

Comment: I think there is a formula that does it for any degree of polynomial. Don't remember it though. Simpsons rule is a private case for N = 2. Do you mean how to select better X values?

Comment: Nice! But you should also add examples in which trapz has higher accuracy. Selesting a higher polynomial degree is not a silver bullet

Comment: @Andrey basically this is Gaussian quadrature with a non-uniform gridm; it is inherently more accurate than the trapezoidal rule.. Not for *all* functions though, that's true, but most anyway.

Comment: At last a nice fast method for nonuniform spacing integration. +1 Great job Rody!

Answer (score 0):

You can do Gaussian quadrature over each piecewise pair of `x` and sum them up to get the complete integral.

Comment: Gaussian quadrature is not meaningful for a fixed set of points, when you cannot choose the point locations. If you mean to do Gaussian quadrature on an interpolated Lagrange polynomial, then this is no better than a simple direct rule.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  This is routinely done in any finite element code - piecewise integration over non-uniform grids.  That's what I'm thinking of.

Comment: WRONG. Yes, finite element codes use a Gaussian integration, to solve a DIFFERENT problem. HOWEVER, given only a list of points sampling a function in one dimension, it is meaningless to do a Gaussian integration. It seems you misunderstand the difference. There is one. A Gaussian integration in 1-d given only that list of points reduces to trapezoidal rule. (All you can meaningfully do is use a midpoint rule for each interval, using a linear interpolation to impute a value, thus trapezoidal rule falls out.)

Comment: If you would use a higher order rule, integrating higher order Lagrange segments, then you might as well integrate a spline, rather than integrating a set of non-differentiable segments. Again, a Gaussian rule is of no value.

Comment: "@Andrey basically this is Gaussian quadrature with a non-uniform gridm; it is inherently more accurate than the trapezoidal rule.. Not for all functions though, that's true, but most anyway." - no value when I write it, inherently more accurate in your comment.  Which is it?

Comment: @duffymo:  Because he is using a spline to interpolate the problem so he can pick points and do one big gaussian quadrature.  You are doing lots of small gaussian quadratures using only two points.

Comment: I get it, Andrew.  I'd argue that it's easier to go lots of small Gaussian quadratures, especially since you already have the points.  What extra accuracy or value is the spline interpolation adding here?